# ListView does not update size with custom view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I made a custom view for my `ListView` My Custom View extends `LinearLayout`, It acts as an expandable Item for a normal `ListView` So the bug I am getting now is really weird, So I have my `ListView` attributes set to

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

So the height is at `wrap_content` lets take a note of that, as that will help us understand the issue.

[image]

So this is the video of how my ListVIew looks. The first `Expandable` Item is visible but the others don't fill the screen, I am pretty confident this is because of `wrap_content` but as soon as I expand one of the item it fill the whole screen. How can I resolve this? My guess is It's because the ListView isn't updating the other items? this is my CustomView code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ExpandableInnerListView extends LinearLayout {
    private ListAdapter adapter;
    private DataChangeObserver dataChangeObserver;
    private View mainView;
    private List<View> reusableViews = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean viewsHidden = true;
    int mDividerHeight = 1;

    public ExpandableInnerListView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ExpandableInnerListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ExpandableInnerListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    }

    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if (this.adapter != null && dataChangeObserver != null) {
            this.adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(dataChangeObserver);
        }
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public void setMainView(View mainView) {
        this.mainView = mainView;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        viewsHidden = !viewsHidden;
        dataChangeObserver.onInvalidated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (adapter != null) {
            dataChangeObserver = new DataChangeObserver();
            adapter.registerDataSetObserver(dataChangeObserver);
            setupView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (adapter != null && dataChangeObserver != null) {
            adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(dataChangeObserver);
            dataChangeObserver = null;
        }
    }

    private void setupView() {
        this.removeAllViews();
        setupMainLayout();
        setupInnerView();

    }

    public void setupMainLayout() {
        if (mainView == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Main View cannot be null!");
        }
        addView(mainView);
    }

    public void setupInnerView() {
        if (viewsHidden) return;
        int reusableCount = reusableViews.size();
        int count = adapter.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View converView = null;
            if (i < reusableCount) {
                converView = reusableViews.get(i);
            }
            View view = adapter.getView(i, converView, this);
            if (i >= reusableCount) {
                reusableViews.add(view);
            }
            if(mDividerHeight > 0) {
                View divider = new View(getContext());
                divider.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(0xFFCCCCCC));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams dividerLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mDividerHeight);
                divider.setLayoutParams(dividerLayoutParams);
                addView(divider);
            }
            addView(view);
        }
    }

    private class DataChangeObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            setupView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
            setupView();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my whole Fragment View XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/back_button_container"
        layout="@layout/kik_back_button" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/native_topbar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/back_button_container"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back_button_container" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_shadow"
        layout="@layout/navbar_underline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/navbar_underline_height"
        android:layout_below="@id/topbar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@android:id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="Search Settings"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@android:id/edit"
        android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/edit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/edit"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_gray"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/edit"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/list_divider_color" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_divider"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="1.0px"
        android:background="@color/list_divider_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No Settings Found"
        android:textSize="19.0sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Would be really generous if someone can spot where the error happens and how to resolve it, and along side if any other error can happen at certain cases.

Comment: I had the similar issue long time ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999997/fragment-doesnt-respect-match-parent-height-when-having-listview-row-item-has-h. But I will suggest you to use expandable listview

Comment: @VivekMishra I can't use Expandable ListView, I have some items in the adapter that aren't expandable like the checkbox's and the summary tabs. :)

Comment: I believe you can control your checkbox behaviour using some Boolean variables

Comment: @VivekMishra is right use expandable `listview`, when some item should not expand then you have to manage this by hiding view or setting inner list size to zero.

Comment: I have already written the code for a working Expandable Item for the ListView, and all my code works with a ListView, I would have to do a lot of hours of recoding if I wanted to switch. I am just gonna wait until someone posts an answer to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like the issue was very minor. I ha to reset the view when I set the mainView

```
public void setMainView(View mainView) {
    this.mainView = mainView;
    setupView();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when new list is updated.

Comment: I don't have access to the adapter within the CustomView. This isn't helpful.